# manifest for xxx:tag not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown

Tags: docker

This is my local images

```
docker images

REPOSITORY                                                                                  TAG                       IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
linkedin/datahub-frontend-react                                                             hb                        e616d0e00d55   19 minutes ago      467MB
linkedin/datahub-frontend-react                                                             head                      e616d0e00d55   19 minutes ago      467MB
linkedin/datahub-gms                                                                        hb                        fc8990fab52d   42 minutes ago      291MB
linkedin/datahub-gms                                                                        head                      fc8990fab52d   42 minutes ago      291MB
```

When I pull linkedin/datahub-frontend-react:hb

```
docker pull linkedin/datahub-frontend-react:hb
Error response from daemon: manifest for linkedin/datahub-frontend-react:hb not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

It's apparent I have image 'linkedin/datahub-frontend-react:hb' in local. Why it said no manifest?

Comment: Just because the image exists locally doesn't mean it exists in any remote repository. It's possible that either (a) you pulled that image sometime in the past, but the named tag no longer exists in the remote repository, or (b) you (or somebody else on the same system) created the `hb` tag locally e.g. by running `docker tag`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command :

docker run ethereum/solc:nightly --help

nightly version contains potentially unstable changes in develop branch